# Allocation for app on iPad 1 is 4x that of iPad 2

Tags: ios, memory, profiling

When I profile my app on an iPad 2, it loads with just under 1MB of allocated memory. When I do the same on an iPad 1, it loads with about 4MB allocated. Both are updated to the same iOS version. Is this normal behavior? If so, is there anything that I can do about it?

Comment: That sounds really strange, does you're application use any floating point code/matrices etc?

Comment: Not when the app first loads, and very little after that.

Comment: So the larger number of registers is out. At the end of the day the memory is only allocated and most of it will probably not be actively used. So it shouldn't make much of a difference.

Comment: Try removing images/media from the project and take a look at the memory. Perhaps the iPad 1 is using @2x images and iPad 2 is using the 1x images? That would explain the 4x memory usage but that seems unlikely the case.

Comment: I think it is due to memory allocation algorithm used by Apple. This algo is different & more efficient for iPad2.

Comment: @Ninja that is impossible. only the new iPad has retina display.

Comment: Do you include device (e.g camera, audio io, ...) dependent Frameworks? The device drivers that then are loaded at startup may differ on the two iPads, since they don't have the same components.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility I would investigate is where the app is storing its resources.  The iPad2 undoubtedly has more vram for textures, sound ram, etc. so it might be storing those resources on the hardware, while the iPad1 would have to store them in host memory and upload them as needed.  A quick way to test this is to down-sample your resources and see if it has a bigger impact on iPad1 than on iPad2, if so then this is a plausible explanation.

For instance, if you have 8MB of graphics, and the iPad1 has 4MB vram available for textures while the iPad2 has 7MB available, then iPad1 will store 4MB of your textures in vram and leave the other 4MB in host ram, while the iPad2 will store 7MB of your textures in vram and leave the other 1MB in host ram.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is sort of normal behavior. It depends on the device type as well. As an example if you analyze memory in a 3G, 3GS, 4, 4S phones you will get different results. This should not be a problem unless it is growing frequently with app usage. What is the os you are using? Have you enabled ARC?